# import comments into chat when comments could get chatty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know sometimes when there's some to and fro, you get a link offering a chat.  And comments are imported into it.

But other times a chat is appropriate and because of no to and fro, it doesn't come up.

In the case of the comments on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/725078/7200rpm-hard-drives-and-types-what-makes-them-so-different/725109#725109)  , some comments may well be very useful, but already after the second comment a mod wrote (understandably given the rules!) "If you want to discuss something, create a chatroom please. Otherwise I'll have to purge the comments here. Comments should be used only to ask for clarification or point out mistakes in a post."

In such an event, it'd be good if comments could be saved and a chat be had. I made a comment offering a chat link (as the mod intelligently suggested), but the chat doesn't import the comments.

Perhaps a good feature would be the ability for a commenter to spawn a link to a chat room that imports the comments.  Or rather than purging or threatening to purge comments, if mods could create a chat link that imports the comments.

Comment: To Daniel Beck, Nowhere does that question you linked to ask or state how to import comments into the chat. My title mentions that is what I am asking.  I know you can create a link to a chat, but just doing that is not what I am asking, see my title.

Comment: The tricky part is how does the system decide which comments to move to chat?  Some comments may be appropriate to stay on the original post, and others are part of the discussion.  The system needs AI to decide which ones to move over.

Comment: Maybe just copy all comments into chat and also leave them behind?